# How to send JavaScript array and retrieve it with PHP array in another page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm new to web programming, my problem is I'm trying to make a CSV file using this PHP code in `ret_data.php`:

```
$data_array = (array data from data_web.php);    
    $csv = "col1,col2 \n";//Column headers
    foreach ($data_array as $record){
    $csv.= $record[0].','.$record[1]."\n"; //Append data to csv
    }

    $csv_handler = fopen ('csvfile.csv','w');
    fwrite ($csv_handler,$csv);
    fclose ($csv_handler);

    echo 'Data saved to csvfile.csv';
```

and trying to get the data from this JavaScript array in `data_web.php`:

```
function store() {
  var TableData = new Array;
  // var TableData = document.getElementById("tbl_users_list").innerHTML;
  $('#tbl_users_list tr').each(function(row, tr) {
    TableData = TableData +
      $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text() + '|' +
      $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text() + '|' +
      $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text() + '|' +
      $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text() + '|' +
      $(tr).find('td:eq(4)').text() + '|' +
      $(tr).find('td:eq(5)').text() + '\n' + ',';
  });
}
```

as you can see I'm trying to get some data from a table using this code. I really appreciate any help or any suggestion. Thank you so much!

Comment: You need to post this data to the server (then its accessible in PHP under `$_POST`). Try reading a bit about this concept https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp
Note that in this case Javascript is in the frontend, and PHP in the backend. They cannot talk to each other directly, but need to send any data over HTTP

Comment: Okay , thanks for the information, i'll try it @RogierSlag